# Возможно ли удалить контейнер list из двумерного контейнера list2?

Tags: c++, list

День добрый!

Вопросик такой:
Есть два списка инициализированных списка:

```
std::list<int> list1 = {1,2,3,4};
std::list<int> list2 = {3,5,6};
```

Есть пустой двумерный список:

```
std::list<std::list<int>> double_list;
```

Я хочу заполнить double_list готовыми list1& list2:

```
double_list.push_back(list1);
double_list.push_back(list2);
```

Теперь двумерный список выглядит так:

```
double_list={{1,2,3,4},
             {3,5,6}};
```

И вдруг я захотел удалить все списки в моем двумерном листе, которые начинаются с элемента '3', чтобы в конечном счете я получил:

```
double_list={{1,2,3,4}};
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью метода [list::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove)

```
// через лямбду
double_list.remove_if([](const auto &list) { 
    return !list.empty() && list.front() == 3; 
});


// через функцию-предикат
bool startWith3(const std::list<int> &list) {
    return !list.empty() && list.front() == 3;
}
double_list.remove_if(startWith3);
```